# chat in iPhone game app using GameKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center, gamekit

I want to implement the inGame chat functionality using GameKit Framework in iphone game app, but is it possible to implement inGame chat without bluetooth? If yes then how? Suppose my game-friend is out of bluetooth rang then how can I chat with my friend?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about using GKPeerPicker for matchmaking, then yes, you can do an Internet-based chat with `GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline`. However, you're going to have to manage the connection yourself. GKPeerPicker only sets up a GKSession for Bluetooth matches.